Prove symmetric matrix $A$ is congruent to $A ^2$ iff $A$ is PSD
How can I solve the following question:

Let ( A ) be a symmetric matrix. Prove that ( A ) is congruent to
( A^2 ) if and only if ( A ) is positive semidefinite (PSD)

I 've no idea where to start from, all I know is:

$A=A^T$

There is $P$ where $P^TAP=A^2$

For PSD matrix all eigenvalues are: $>=0$



What do we know about the entries of $A$?  (this is likely an assumption given somewhere before the question... if it's a textbook, it might even be earlier in the chapter/textbook)

2 is not assumed. It is an (incomplete) definition of one side of your iff. Didn't you try to prove any of the two directions of this iff? What do you know about diagonalizability of (real! as Brian alerts you)  symmetric matrices?
